# exactly why this error are show i can't understand. this is the mongoose conncetion with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

connection.once('open', () => {console.log('DB Connected!')}).catch((err) => {
^

TypeError: connection.once(...).catch is not a function

This error are shows when server started
[image]

I need help to solve this error

Comment: Pls show the code and more info and write your answer correctly so I can help you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL` is not a string.

Typically, when this happens, your environment variable is undefined.

There are two common places you set your environment variables:

1. Inside a configuration file
2. Inside a script in the `package.json` file

Based on the error, if the environment variable is not a string, it is likely undefined. If you are setting the environment variable with one of the two methods listed above, be sure it is a string.

Otherwise, you may not be setting it at all, and in this case, set it in one of those two ways.